# integration of yeoman 1.0 with express

Tags: angularjs, express, yeoman

I have an AngularJs Web App which I build with Yeoman, would like to integrate Express into the mixture. The last part is what I am stuck on.  I have Yeoman (1.0) aka Yo which basically uses Grunt and Bower but unfortunately serves all the files off its static server.
How would I write a GruntFile to have Yeoman 1.0 serving off the Express and not a Yo's baked in server and what should be the project's dir structure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `grunt-contrib-connect`, which is the Yeoman default, with [`grunt-express`](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express). It accepts a [`server` configuration setting](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express#server) which you can use to provide custom logic behind certain routes.

Comment: In addition to Passy's comments, check out the grunt express example:  
https://github.com/blai/grunt-express-example 
and compare it with: Addy Osmani's experiement Express/Yeoman/AngularJS stack (which unfortunately uses Yeoman 0.9.6)
https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/tree/express-stack/demo
Good Luck